# How do I make a 3D Graph in R -- and is that the right choice?

Tags: r, graph, 3d

I'm trying to make a graph to see the differences in student testing by age and their school rating. I could very easily make a normal scatterplot with student test scores by age and another for student test scores by school rating.

I could also make the graph with the school's rating on the x-axis, with age on one side of the y-axis and rating on the other. But while it's better than having two graphs -- it obviously doesn't show much more than that.

The idea here is that there is a correlation between not only school rating and test score, but also school rating and age -- so I'd like to figure out the best way to show that, since their age and rating both correlate with score. And a 16-year-old in a lower-rated school should be given more slack on their scores than a 16-year-old in a higher-rated school.

My original thought was that the x-axis would be the 1-10 ratings, while the test scores would be one y-axis and the age would be the z. But after looking it up for a while, I couldn't get `surface3d()` to work or `scatterplot3d()`, etc. These might've been functions I would need to load in -- but since I'm pretty new to R, I'm not sure. I'd be happy to download the correct package if somebody could point me in its direction.

A subset of this data looks like this:

`Rating Score   Age
1   54.911  13
1   85.665  18
3   66.246  13
3   83.103  17
3   88.556  17
3   80.631  18
4   90.562  17
4   77.799  14
4   78.771  16
5   87.912  17
6   92.113  15
7   89.275  15
7   93.556  16
7   63.177  16
7   78.258  18
8   76.116  14
9   96.351  18
9   85.06   16
9   85.664  17
10  88.487  15`

There's the obvious possibility that I'm also thinking about this in the wrong way as well -- and I might have to switch my thought-process to learn how to make a bubble plot or something.

But all help and ideas are appreciated, thanks!
(And sorry for partially asking two questions in one.)

*Edit:
Here's a quick graph in Excel with these values showing a positive correlation between both -- I'd just like a way to make it less messy and more intuitive:*

[image: Test Scores]

Comment: It might be better to plot in two-dimensions and use colored grouping, like Age.

Comment: `pairs()` might be useful, too.

Comment: We're pretty well conditioned to look for response variables on the y-axis. If you're interested in differences in score, and you think score depends more or less on on age and school ranking, you should put score on the y-axis. Putting more than one variable on the y-axis is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: @shujaa        Definitely -- I don't disagree with that at all. I started with Test Score in the y-axis, but it looked messier because it didn't show two clear correlations like it does in the x-axis (though it's very counter intuitive). It works down there because age and rating both correlate against test score -- but there's no correlation between school rating and age, obviously. Ideally School Rating would be the x-axis, I'm just unsure of how to show it well.

Comment: To make `scatterplot3d` available, you'll need to install the package containing the function (in this case the package is also called `scatterplot3d`): `install.packages('scatterplot3d')`. You can then do something like: `scatterplot3d(d$Rating, d$Score, d$Age, type='h')`, assuming your data are in data.frame `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your data `df`, (I loaded it from your question in the clipboard)

```
df <- read.table(file = "clipboard", header = T)
```

Installing the package if you don't have it (If you do have it installed, just `require(scatterplot3d)` will work)

```
if(!require(scatterplot3d)) {
  install.packages("scatterplot3d")
  require(scatterplot3d)
}
```

Make a plot

```
with(df, scatterplot3d(x = Rating, y = Age, z = Score))
```

A 3d plot isn't terrible here. You can also do 2d plots with color:

```
if(!require(ggplot2)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
  require(ggplot2)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = Rating, y = Score, color = Age)) +
    geom_point()

ggplot(df, aes(x = Age, y = Score, color = Rating)) +
    geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The 3D scatterplot worked very well. However, I'd like to see it on a 2D plot with colors -- but after running with the code above, I got the error: "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function." Any ideas?

Comment: I used `df` for the data.frame, which you see in `ggplot(df...` (and in the `with(df...` for the 3d scatterplot), but `df` is also a function in R (for the F distribution). Wherever I have `df` in my code, you need to replace it with whatever your data.frame is called.

Comment: Bah, obviously, sorry -- thought I did that. One more question on the 3D scatterplot -- which showed pretty much exactly what I was expecting -- do you know how to get more tick-marks and graph-reading ease added? It was a bit tough to figure out looking just in its help folder. The correlation's clear, but it's difficult to track certain points back to the axes without more lines and help. Thanks again!

Comment: Depending on how much data you have you could use `type="h"` as jbaums suggested. The default number of tickmarks is about 5 on the x and 5 on the y axis, of length 7 (see this if you run `par("lab")`. You can change this in `scatterplot3d` by passing it `lab = (10, 10, 7), lab.z = 10` for 10 tick marks per axis.

Comment: Nice use of `'clipboard'`! OS X users can do something similar with `df <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), header=TRUE)` (just in case there are OS X R folks trying to work with your example).

Answer (score 1):

It might look better in two dimensions, grouped by Age (or Rating).  The `lattice` package is nice for these types of plots.  Anything can be adjusted.  This one is colored by Age.  Assuming your data is `d`,

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Rating ~ Score, data = d, groups = Age,
       auto.key = list(title = "Age", space = "right", cex = 1.0),
       par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 19, cex = 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is great. When I start doing this with more than six ages -- is there a way to group by years of five or years of ten and do the same thing?

Comment: Sure, you can just split the data into the desired groups for that.

Comment: could also do something like `data$age.groups <- cut(data$Age, pretty(data$Age, 3), right=TRUE)` and `color=age.groups` (making manual breaks would work, too)